# Are git repositories copyable?

Tags: git

When you `git init` or `git clone` a folder the folder will be marked as a repository and it will contain an invisible (in Windows) folder named `.git`.

If I would just move the contents of the repository + the `.git` folder to another folder or another computer would that cause any problems with my local repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Local Paths

The only time you will have trouble with this AFAIK is when you have references to remotes that are local to the system. For instance,

```
[foo@bar ~]$ cd /tmp/
[foo@bar tmp]$ mkdir git1
[foo@bar tmp]$ cd git1/
[foo@bar git1]$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/git1/
[foo@bar git1]$ cd ..
[foo@bar tmp]$ git clone file:///tmp/git1/ git2
Cloning into 'git2'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.
[foo@bar tmp]$ cd git2/
[foo@bar git2]$ git remote -v
origin  file:///tmp/git1/ (fetch)
origin  file:///tmp/git1/ (push)
[foo@bar git2]$
```

This will obviously break your remotes if you move the repo. Otherwise I think you should be fine.

### `config` Caution

Also be aware, if you are doing this for the purpose of sharing the code with someone other than yourself, all of your local `git config` values are going to be transferred as well since they are stored under `.git/config`. So if just copy the folder and give it to someone else they will have all your values (that is if they aren't set globally), such as your email, name, editor preferences, etc. which they will have to reset appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous job we had a repo that contained binaries and was very large. Cloning it would take almost an hour so instead when new hire joined, we'd copy the whole directory (content + .git dir) on a USB drive and pass it around. We never had any issue.

Comment: You might try a shallow clone in this case, if you don't need to old often history this can make cloning *much* faster, i.e. `git clone --depth 20` or whatever number you like.

Comment: If you put the repo on the USB drive, clone/copy it, and make the USB drive itself the remote, you can pass it around when someone needs to push changes. That way you can even work together without having a network.

Comment: The USB thingie was only used instead of the clone. Once the new dev had the files, he/she would just do pull / push and use GIT normally. I guess we didn't know about the `--depth` param back then. :)

Answer (score 0):

All the information git needs to manage a repo is stored in the .git folder (in fact, that is the repo). Moving it would be fine. The only issue you might run into is moving between machines this way, you might lose your global git config settings.